# Infinite sum with recursive coefficients

Tags: summation, algebraic-manipulation

*Mathematica* can handle infinite sums like

```
Sum[ x^k/k!, {k, 0, Infinity}]
(* Exp[x] *)
```

Suppose I only know a recursive definition of the coefficients `a[k_] = 1/k!`

```
a[k_ /; IntegerQ[k]] := Which[k == 0, 1, True, a[k - 1]/k]
```

MMA evaluates the finite sum

```
Sum[a[k] x^k , {k, 0, 5}]
(* 1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + x^5/120 *)
```

as expected.

How can I force MMA to evaluate the infinite sum?

```
Sum[a[k] x^k , {k, 0, Infinite}] 
(* \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(\[Infinity])](\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(k\)]\ a[k]\)\) *)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use `RSolveValue` to get the coefficient? E.g., `FullSimplify[RSolveValue[{a[k] == a[k - 1]/k, a[0] == 1}, a[k], k]]`

Comment: Thanks. I'm not looking for a solution of this easy example. I'm looking for  a way to force MMA to apply the recursion in an infinite sum(as MMA  did in the finite sum)

Comment: I suspect no algorithm exists that can compute an infinite summation directly from a recurrence (that is, without first computing an explicit form). As for actually performing infinite recursion, I don't recommend it...

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: What a pity, thanks